# Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

Tags: kali-linux, nmap, metasploit

Im using Armitage on Kali Linux 2. (Virtual box) In Armitage Im using "Quick scan (OS detect)" option. This is output log:

```
[*] Nmap: Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.255 
[*] Nmap: Host is up (0.0089s latency). 
[*] Nmap: All 100 scanned ports on 192.168.1.255 are filtered 
[*] Nmap: Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details 
[*] Nmap: OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/
[*] Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (256 hosts up) scanned in 435.84 seconds
```

It didnt detect any OS.
I have already disabled firewall and its still not working.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The address 192.168.1.255/24 is **not** a host address. It is the broadcast-address. That is also the reason why it says

> [*] Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (256 hosts up) scanned in 435.84 seconds.

In a network with 256 IP-addresses there can only be 254 hosts, because the first address (192.168.1.0/24) is the network-ID and the last address (192.168.1.255/24) is the broadcast-address.

Comment: but still there is no hosts with detected OS. The OS is "unknown" for every host
Also i was scanning 192.168.1.0/24

Comment: try typing      db_nmap --min-hostgroup 96 -sV -n -T4 -O -F --version-light 192.168.1.0/24      in your Armitage console

Comment: it still says Too many fingerprints match this host to give specific OS details

Comment: I could reproduce it, I'll look what it means.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30747316) and [this](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect-fingerprint-format.html) should help.

Comment: Thanks for helping, this whole time my VM was using NAT instead of Bridged Adapter.